# Как отдать ссылку на файл на другом сервере

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте,  есть удаленный линукс сервер на котором хранятся файлы, примерно по такому пути:   `/opt/glassfish/blabla/файлы.`

На другом компьютере сайт на php, на фреймворке codeigniter.  Мне нужно как-то сделать, чтобы при клике по ссылке и попадания в контроллер, можно было можно было скачать файл с первого сервера.

Мне сказали, что нужно сделать ссылки на файлы и хранить их в базе.  Но я не совсем понимаю как должны эти ссылки выглядеть, как их создавать. Для попадания на первый сервер  нужны логин и пароль, должны ли они присутствовать в ссылке?

Мои поиски в гугле постоянно заканчиваются вокруг хелперов "download" и "ftp", но первый позволяет скачать что-то со своей машины, а второй - залить что-то на удаленный сервер, или что-то там поменять.

Не могли бы вы объяснить мне по поводу ссылок?

Comment: Для начала определись, по какому протоколу собираешься забирать файлы с сервера. Вариантов много: ftp, http и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался со своей проблемой, на момент задавания вопросов я плохо понимал, что мне нужно, поэтому плохо задал вопрос и получил плохие ответы.
На линукс сервере , чтобы с него качать файлы нужно было написать интерфейс, который по http или ftp протоколу отдавал бы файлы.

В моем случае это получился сервлет написанный на JAVA...

```
@WebServlet(name = "getExcelFile", urlPatterns = {"/getExcelFile"})
    public class GetExcelFile extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String fileName = request.getParameter("filename");
            // полный путь к файлу
            String fileNameFullPath = ExcelPath.EXCEL_PATH.concat(fileName);

            if ((new File(fileNameFullPath)).exists()) {
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=".concat(fileName) );
                try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()); FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileNameFullPath)) {
                    int c;
                    while ((c = fis.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(c);
                    }
                    bos.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Дальше нужно  по адресу [http://(IP):(PORT)/(Название_проекта)/getExcelFile?filename=](http://(IP):(PORT)/(%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)/getExcelFile?filename=)'   ввести название файла и если он есть, то он будет доступен для загрузки.

Answer (score -1):

Пробовали создать сервер на первом компьютере и скачивать с него?
Например, nginx или apache.
Тогда для скачивания путь будет что-то вроде `<внешний ip>/имя файла`, а внутренний `<..>/public`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Для того, чтобы отдавать файлы есть два вида серверов: http - apache (или nginx) и файловый - FTP.
После этого можно будет получить внешнюю ссылку на файл вида 
http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/<имя директории>/<имя файла> (для http варианта).

Comment: * Два наиболее извесных